# Почему таблица стилей передается с типом text/html?

Tags: java, css, jsp

Подключаю таблицу стилей в jsp странице:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/style.css">
```

при загрузке страницы, в консоли браузера выводится предупреждение:

> *Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type
>   text/html*

Соответственно таблица стилей не работает, помогите решить данную проблему!

Сервер Tomcat 9, И Glassfish 5

servlet-api 2.4

java 1.8

UPD.

С подключенной таблицей стилей
[image: При подключении таблицы стилей]

без
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
         version="2.4">
    <jsp-config>
        <jsp-property-group>
            <url-pattern>/WEB-INF/pages/*</url-pattern>
            <include-prelude>/WEB-INF/jspf/header.jspf</include-prelude>
            <include-coda>/WEB-INF/jspf/footer.jspf</include-coda>
        </jsp-property-group>
    </jsp-config>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mainServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.opencode.test.servlets.MainServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>registrationServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.opencode.test.servlets.RegistrationServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>loginServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.opencode.test.servlets.LoginServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mainServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>registrationServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/registration</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>loginServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>loginServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/logout</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Comment: Покажите `web.xml`. Возможно `css/style.css` не попадает в фильтр.

Comment: @defaultlocale Добавил. Если убрать маппинг на MainServlet то все работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы привязать `mainServlet` к корню используйте пустую строку:

```xml
 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mainServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern></url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Шаблон `/` переопределяет сервлет по-умолчанию. Соответственно, в такой конфигурации все запросы, не попадающие в другие сервлеты (в т.ч. `/css/*`), обрабатываются `mainServlet`, а не сервлетом Tomcat по-умолчанию.

Из [спецификации](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/servlet-3_1-fr-eval-spec/index.html):

> 12.2 Specification of Mappings
>
> In the Web application deployment descriptor, the following syntax is used to define mappings:
>   ...
>
> - The empty string ("") is a special URL pattern that exactly maps to the
>     application's context root, i.e., requests of the form `http://host:port/<contextroot>/`.
>     In this case the path info is ’/’ and the servlet path and context path is
>     empty string (““).
> - A string containing only the ’/’ character indicates the "default" servlet of the
>     application. In this case the servlet path is the request URI minus the context path
>     and the path info is null

Comment: Спасибо, за развернутый ответ.